# Bootstrap navbar collapse not styled correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsable navbar in bootstrap that is not showing correctly when collapsed. I am moving the navbar-header (which contains a navbar-brand) to the right side with pull-right. However, adding this in seems to make the navbar that is toggled sit between the toggle button and the navbar-brand.
I would like the toggled navbar to sit below the button and the brand whenever it is open.

This is the correctly formatted version, however, the Brand is not pulled over to the right
[image]

This is what is happening when I pull the Brand over
[image]

Here is the code I am using. Bootstrap version is 3.3.6

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try removing pull-right class from navbar-header and add .navbar-brand{ float:right;} to your css like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/chrfzen5/2/

Comment: The Brand is moved over to the left whenever the navbar is expanded. I would prefer if it stays to the right at all times

Comment: updated https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/chrfzen5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.pos-rel{ position:relative;}
.navbar-brand{position:absolute; right:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container pos-rel">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="pull-right" id="mobile-nav">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right" id="com-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setNavbarBrand();
    });

    $(window ).resize(function () {
        setNavbarBrand();
    });

    function setNavbarBrand() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            $('#mobile-nav').show();
            $('#com-nav').hide();
        } else {
            $('#mobile-nav').hide();
            $('#com-nav').show();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I had this code before, however, when expanded, the Brand moves back to the left side of the links